# Crack 512-bit RSA encrypted messages without a private key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I was wondering if it would be possible to crack a message that was encrypted with 512-bit PCKS1 encryption with the public key. I am doing a project for our science fair type thing at school and have created a simple messaging app that sends encrypted messages.

Would it be possible to decrypt these messages in a suitable amount of time (A couple of hours on a $5 DigitalOcean droplet) or is that totally ridiculous? If that idea isn't so far fetched, could you please also suggest a program to use for the cracking?

Comment: Of course it's possible to decrypt it, there still hasn't been an encryption standard that absolutely can not be broken (and the only way I think that would be possible would be embedding some sort of AI in it to dynamically prevent it from being broken). And I mean... the NSA can do it, so of course it's possible. I don't know how to do it though, I just know it's possible, and there are more than one ways of doing it.

Comment: @Cestarian, thanks for your input, I understand the NSA can do it but do you think that there is any chance I could do it in say a couple of hours, no I do not own a super computer :P

Comment: Honestly I don't know, it is probably possible either through a fault in the encryption algorithm (there's usually a hole in there somewhere) or a deliberately placed backdoor, if one is in place. I'm not really a crypto guy. But forcefully breaking the encryption you can not do as far as I know. At least not without that super computer you don't have, or so we tend to be told ;)

But if someone has found a way, it's doubtful that you'll be able to get access to that method for free, unless it's already public knowledge, in which case google would give you the answer.

Comment: Since I said that, I got a bit interested and decided to google up on this... Look what I found.

http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/173108-researchers-crack-the-worlds-toughest-encryption-by-listening-to-the-tiny-sounds-made-by-your-computers-cpu

That's with physical proximity, and there have been wide claims of 512-bit RSA being "cracked" in anywhere from 6 weeks to 12 microseconds (not all of these claims are credible though, but some are bound to be true)

Comment: Decrypt it using the key, sure. Crack it, not with the given hardware restrictions. Perhaps you should clear up your question to specify crack (I think that's what you mean).

Comment: @Cestarian Thanks for that article, it's really interesting but a little too complicated for what I'm looking for. I'll google it and post anything I find interesting here.

Comment: I don't know if there is an easy to use solution by now, but in principle it's possible to factor 512 bit RSA keys for about $100. See [Is 512-bit RSA still safe for signature generation?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/is-512-bit-rsa-still-safe-for-signature-generation)

Comment: Last number I heard was $75. From the [*Factoring as a Service* paper](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/10/breaking-512-bit-rsa-with-amazon-ec2-is-a-cinch-so-why-all-the-weak-keys/). Their [python source code is on GitHub](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~nadiah/projects/faas/). (Haven't tried it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

512 bit RSA was factored in 1999 with pretty advanced specialized hardware. It took 6 months. It should be much easier (though not trivial) today with modern PCs.

From Wikipedia

> In 2009, Benjamin Moody factored an RSA-512 bit key in 73 days using only public software (GGNFS) and his desktop computer (dual-core Athlon64 at 1,900 MHz). Just under 5 gigabytes of disk was required and about 2.5 gigabytes of RAM for the sieving process.

That was about 7 years ago. Going by those stats, I am guessing a few modern desktop computers with intel i7 chips  working together would factor 512-bit RSA within days or weeks. I doubt you can do it in a couple of hours though.